# Spectator interference in Quidditch

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

In baseball, there have been issues with spectators catching balls in the outfield, and there are subsequent rules in place for spectator interference. Are there any spectator interference rules in Quidditch?

Specifically:

- Hermione (as a spectator) casts the Impervius charm on Harry's glasses so that he can see in the rain. Is this Kosher?
- What happens if a spectator catches the snitch?
- Very related to the previous: what happens if a spectator deflects the snitch toward or away from one particular seeker?

Are these actions permitted? And what would be the recourse?

Comment: I've always wondered the same thing!!

Comment: ans it seems like in Quidditch, a lot of things are allowed. Harry seems like the kind of person who wouldn't cheat at quidditch, too

Comment: What I'm wondering is if they'd even be able to enforce these rules. In the first book, both Snape and Quirrel were casting spells on Harry's broom, and it seemed like no one in the entire stadium knew what was going on.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - It wasn't a pro-game. It's a kids game played with wonky brooms and inexperienced flyers.

Comment: @Valorum but they still took it all very seriously, even professionally. When Malfoy grabbed Harry's broom to prevent him from catching the Snitch, it was considered a serious foul. Even McGonagall was outraged

Comment: @Valorum :

But it was a pro-game. There are professional leagues and even a world cup.

Comment: @G.Van - The game that Quirrell interfered with wasn't a pro-game. It was a school game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an incident of crowd interference in [Quidditch Through the Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages). We learn that the Ministry has used defensive spells to take preventative measures (in league games) against the sort of low-level interference that Hermione undertook.

> *Refereeing a Quidditch match was once a task for only the bravest witches and wizards. Zacharias Mumps tells us that a Norfolk referee called Cyprian Youdle died during a friendly match between local wizards in 1357. The originator of the curse was never caught but is believed to have been a member of the crowd. While there have been no proven referee slayings since, **there have been several incidences of broom-tampering over the centuries,** the most dangerous being the transformation of the referee’s broom into a Portkey, so that he or she is whisked away from the match halfway through and turns up months later in the Sahara Desert. **The Department of Magical Games and Sports has issued strict guidelines on the security measures relating to players’ brooms and these incidents are now, thankfully, extremely rare.***

In short, crowd interference is very rare, presumably quite easy to detect (for an experienced referee) and quite easy to prove once it's taken place.

There are no stated guidelines regarding what would happen if the snitch is meddled with, other than that the referee has a wide leeway to deal with unexpected issues. Presumably it would simply be put back into play or (if physically handled) replaced with a fresh one.

Comment: If it was put back into play then it would no longer be able to detect the DNA of the winning Seeker in the event of a disputed catch.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Good point. See edit